# Syntax error when inserting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to get familiar with MySQL and getting frustrated.

I am trying to create a function...

```
use mystuff;
DELIMITER $$
create PROCEDURE spUpdateCodeTable(
   IN mcodeID INT,
   IN mtableCode CHAR(5), 
   IN mDescription VARCHAR(100), 
   IN mCode CHAR(5), 
   IN mgroupCode CHAR(5), 
   IN mt1 VARCHAR(100), 
   IN mt2 VARCHAR(100), 
   IN mt3 VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
   UPDATE codeTable SET 
      tableCode =mtableCode,
      Description=mDescription,
      Code=mCode,
      groupCode=mgroupCode,
      t1=mt1,
      t2=mt2,
      t3=mt3,
      chaDate=NOW()
   WHERE codeID = mcodeID;

   IF (ROW_COUNT() < 1)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO codeTable (tableCode,Description,Code,groupCode,t1,t2,t3,createDate)
      VALUES (mtableCode,mDescription,mCode,mgroupCode,mt1,mt2,mt3,NOW());
   END;      
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure compiled fine when I only had the UPDATE section, but as soon as I added the insert four lines (starting at the IF (ROW_COUNT()....),I started getting ....

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'BEGIN
   INSERT INTO codeTable (tableCode, Description, Code, groupCode,t1,t2,t' at line 23'`

Comment: [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html). tl;dr - `IF ... THEN ... END IF;`

Comment: If you put a `#` at the beginning of a line it indicates a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Phil said, you'll be wanting...

```
IF (ROW_COUNT() < 1) THEN
  INSERT INTO codeTable (tableCode,Description,CODE,groupCode,t1,t2,t3,createDate)
  VALUES (mtableCode,mDescription,mCode,mgroupCode,mt1,mt2,mt3,NOW());
END IF;
```

instead of what you have.

Aren't MySQL error messages for stored procedures just wonderful?